# Get Http body in Apache Camel not working if content-type not presented

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-camel

Working with apache camel, I found something interesting, something I should fix in my case... So, I have POST route, which works on different types of urls etc, I mean, I should get the http body inside my processor.

I must be able to read for example this one:

```
curl -X POST -d'a=b'  http://localhost:8080/........  (DOESN'T WORK)
```

or (which is the same)

```
curl -X POST --data 'a=b'  http://localhost:8080/........ (DOESN'T WORK)
```

And it **doesn't work!** But it works when I add Content-type header in request:

```
curl -X POST -H"Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d'a=b'  http://localhost:8080/........  (WORKS)
```

or EVEN INVALID (!!)

```
curl -X POST -H"Content-type: xxxxxxx" -X POST -d'a=b'  http://localhost:8080/........ (WORKS)
```

it **WORKS**!

(Just in case, how I get the body in code in Processor):

```
String mainBody = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
if(mainBody == null || mainBody.isEmpty()) {
    LOG.error("EMPTY!");
} else {
    LOG.error("FOUND " + mainBody);
}
```

Strange thing? 
During debugging realized that default Content-type is **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**. And when I do

```
curl -X POST -H"Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST -d'a=b'  http://localhost:8080/........ (DOESN'T WORK)
```

it **doesn't work** too.

So my issue is how to let it work always? I don't have some special formats, content-types etc, my thing should just redirect whole body to 3rd party and it should consume all content-types (even if not specified). How can I do that?

P.S. My XML config is

```
<rests id="rests" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <rest id="rest-custom">
     .....
       <post uri="/?matchOnUriPrefix=true&amp;bridgeEndpoint=true" method="POST">
            <description>....</description>
            <route>
                <process ref="unknownPostRedirectProcessor" />
                <to uri="direct:commonRoute" />
            </route>
        </post>
    </rest>
```

This "post" catches all post requests, and it works fine except the described problem.

Comment: what is your rest component configuration?

Comment: Edited my queston

Answer (score 1):

Use `curl -v` to see `curl` inserting `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` by default for `POST` method.

Consider setting `Exchange.SKIP_WWW_FORM_URLENCODED` exchange property to `true` to prevent Camel binding the request parameters to Camel headers if you need access to the raw body of the HTTP request.

Comment: @DenDoeson have a look at the [Exchange::setProperty method](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.apache.camel/camel-api/3.1.0/org/apache/camel/Exchange.html#setProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-)